# Const not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get data through an an API built on Node (first time using node).

This is the code i have written according to the documentation:
[GitHub Documentation](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec)

```
npm install boxrec -g
const boxrec = require("boxrec").Boxrec;
```

However I keep encountering this error message:

```
const : The term 'const' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ const boxrec = require("boxrec").Boxrec;
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (const:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Are you trying to run this in command line? `npm install boxrec -g` will install this package in your global repo on your system. `const boxrec = required("boxrec").Boxrec` will work if it's in a file like `index.js` then you run `node index.js` from the command line

Comment: @Andrei I was trying to run each line in my command line. Just for clarity, you are saying save const boxrec in a file then run node index.js in command line? trying that throws a module not found error message in command line

Comment: `npm install boxrec -g` is a NPM command, you can run it in your bash terminal. `const boxrec = require("boxrec").Boxrec;` is JavaScript, you can run it with the Node shell (you can start a node shell with the command `node`) or in a JS file.

Comment: That error message looks like a PowerShell error - you need to run the code inside a node.js environment, as has been suggested.

Comment: @Emm here's a quick read about the difference between local and `-g` flag https://flaviocopes.com/npm-packages-local-global/. It's highly recommended to use local instead of global. You should instead do `npm install boxrec` in the directory of your project so that you can then reference it in `index.js` as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the terminal or command line for commands like `npm install {package-name}` the `-g` flag is only if you want it to be installed and available for multiple projects or as a command line function.

in your case you could just use `C:\>boxrec` will run the tool right away you would probably need additional arguments to use it.

> Not every npm package is a **Command Line Tool** some are just JavaScript libraries to help you develop

Once you have installed the package you can use it in development in a JavaSript file run the following

```
const boxrec = require("boxrec").Boxrec;

// now boxrec can be used
const cookieJar = await boxrec.login(BOXREC_USERNAME, BOXREC_PASSWORD);
var person = await boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar, 352);
```

to run the code you'd need to run `node login.js`

Comment: Tried running node index.js in my powershell after writing this code out and got this error message: 

'const cookieJar = await boxrec.login('xx',xxx');
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function'

Comment: yeah, that's going into JavaScript now. You'll need to learn about `promises` and `async/await` pattern. You can wrap the 2 lines that use `await` within an async function call. example `async function loginUser() { //code with await }` then call your function to execute `loginUser()`. It's a bit outside the original scope of your question